# Update only a range of data from one mysql table to another

Tags: mysql, range

I have inherited a database (mysql) consisting of dates and times for each day for the year 2014.

The table contains the following columns (only)

```
date, time1, time2, time3
01- Jan, 08:00, 12:00, 16:00
02- Jan, 08:02, 12:02, 16:02
```

I have been given an excel document with updated times that need to be copied into the database.

After hours of cleaning up the excel, and making it reflect the structure of the db, I finally managed to create a new table with the updated times.

However here is the issue I have:

I need to copy the new times from the new table into the old table only from 01- June to 31- December. All older times in the old db need to stay intact.

I have access to phpmyadmin.

I am unsure about the sql query that I need to use.

Any help would be really appreciated. (I am not happy with the way the db has been designed, the lack of auto incremented ID column makes it challenging for me. Otherwise I could have said "update all fields time1, time2, time3 for IDs xx - xx or something along those lines).

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. Couldn't you just delete in the old table rows from 01 June to 31 December, and insert the new data corresponding to these dates?

Comment: if i understand correctly, your date column is not of `Date` data type since it only has the Day and the Month stored. It would be much easier if you would add a temporary column that adds a year to all those dates and use the WHERE date BETWEEN 'datefrom' AND 'dateto'